# Using regex to find emails (Theory question)

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Okay so I wrote code to take a text file, find all the emails in it, remove duplicate emails put the remaining emails in a new list, and then write that list to a new file.

```
import re

textFile = open("/Users/Name/Documents/EmailList.txt", "r")
contents = textFile.read()
emails = re.findall("([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)", contents) 
counter = 0
emailList = [] 

for email in emails:
    if email not in emailList:
        emailList.append(email)
        counter = counter + 1

print ('The Number of emails in this list is: ' + str(counter))

newList = open("New_Email_List.txt","w+")

for email in emailList:
    newList.write("%s\n" % email)
newList.close()
```

Okay so this code is fully functional, but I have a question...

My code was not writing the emails to the file new_email_list until I changed :

```
for email in emails:
    newList.write("%s\n" % email)
newList.close()
```

to

```
for email in emailList:
    newList.write("%s\n" % email)
newList.close()
```

Why couldn't the code iterate through the original regex pattern again as it did in the first for loop?

Comment: I'm not being able to replicate the behavior that you're describing in windows with python 3.7.1.

Comment: unrelated to your question but to handle duplicates there is a set data structure in the standard library

Comment: What exactly is the issue here, i am able to run the code with both emails and emailList.

Comment: I tried locally, it seems to work fine. Can you try again ?

Comment: I wonder if you didn't used finditer instead of findall in a previous version, it  does not return a list but an iterator that is consumed on iteration.

Comment: The only cause I can imagine to the behavior you describe is that the two for loops use the same iterator, which is not reset after the first loop. Not the behavior I expect from your code, though.